# Why does the YouTube app know what I have watched on youtube.com in Safari

Tags: safari, permission, youtube

The YouTube app seems to have access to Safari's cookies because if you watch a youtube video in Safari, the app knows it.

Is there a permissions setting to prevent this?

Is this not an alarming permissions leak?

Comment: Are you logged into the same Google account on this (and other) device(s)?

Comment: Yes, but not in the Safari session

Comment: Follow these steps and tell me what happens: (1) Watch a video in Safari (2) Open the YouTube app and go to Library > History (3) Does the video show up there?

Comment: Please double check that you're _definitely_ not logged into Google/YouTube (either) on Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Your YouTube history is affiliated with your Google account. This is the same affiliation that allows you to keep track of your liked videos and any playlists you may make and channels you subscribe to. Any browsers/apps which are logged into your Google account will have the same information about your view history.

Comment: I am not logged into Google in Safari